# How to install plugins in video.js

Tags: video.js

I am not a developer so I am asking you to be patient with me, someone was patient with you ;) . I cannot understand how can I install plugins for video.js ! Do I upload .CSS and .js files on the plugin folder of my site. Do I include any code on the page of my site where I want to place the video.? I am particulary interested in the resolution plugin. As I understood I upload the 2 files ( .CSS and .js ) and then put that piece of code in the page where I want to make the video appear. Well nothing really happens :(.
Help!

Comment: include the piece of code you are referencing

Comment: https://github.com/vidcaster/video-js-resolutions: This is the page of that specific plugin. How do I "activate" that plugin?